# Semantic consequence in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm reading [Introduction to Mathematical logic](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/IntroMathLogic/Fullbook_Draft.pdf) by Sam Buss. I'm currently going through propositional logic and I can't understand  why (c) is correct:

> Theorem I.13. Suppose that Γ and ∆ are sets of formulas, and Γ ⊆ ∆.
>
> (a) If φ satisfies ∆, then φ satisfies Γ.
>
> (b) If ∆ is satisfiable, then Γ is also satisfiable.
>
> (c) If Γ ⊧ A, then ∆ ⊧ A.

(a) and (b) make perfect sense to me. Γ should be satisfiable when Δ (a set with additional formulas) is satisfiable. But why is (c) correct when we don't know if the additional formulas in Δ could make the set unsatisfiable? Apologies if this is an extremely elementary question

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I think you should double-check the definition of "$\Gamma \models A$" (I.10) and write out what (c) is saying if you "expand" this definition, and then check if it still doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, will go over that one again. I also identify with Psyduck so you're cool in my book

Comment: In a nutshell, we may always add un-necessary premises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Γ ⊧ A$ means that every $\phi$ that makes all $B \in \Gamma$ true will make $A$ true as well. By adding more premises we won't lose any of these truth-preserving valuations. Given any $\phi$: Either it satisfies $\Delta$ - then it also satisfies $\Gamma$, and by $\Gamma \vDash A$ we have that $A$ will be true under this $\phi$ as well. Or $\phi$ does not satisfy $\Gamma$, in which case the truth value for $A$ does not matter. In any event, we get that any $\phi$ that satisfies $\Delta$ will satisfy $A$ as well, which is exactly $\Delta \vDash A$.

Comment: Let's say that `Γ = {p}` and `Δ = {p, ¬p}` and we choose `A = p`.
It seems to me that (c) can't hold using this example

Comment: If $Δ = \{p, ¬p\}$ then the premises are inconsistent (= contradictory), and everything follows. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion.

Comment: In particular, $p$ already follows from $\Delta$  trivially because it is included in it. The additional $\neg p$ can't remove a conclusion we already obtained.